# Got to Get the value to the controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

```
<div> <% foreach (var item in Model)
         { %>


          <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model =>item.Customer) %>
             <%: Html.Encode(item.Customer) %>
        </div>

         <%break; %>

         <%} %></div>
         <p></p>

          <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="Create New"  />
```

Need the value in item.Customer to be sent To the Controller Through the "Create New Button"

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to put the value in a hidden form field and then add that field as a parameter to the controller action to which the form posts.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you start a form that submits the appropriate controller/action. Second, store the value in a hidden field (via the `HiddenFor` extension method):

```
<% using(Html.BeginForm("YourAction","YourController)) { %>
    <div>
        <% foreach(var item in Model){ %>
            <div class="editor-label">
                <%= Html.LabelFor(model => item.Customer) %>
                <%= Html.HiddenFor(model => item.Customer %>
            </div>
        <% } %>
        <p></p>
        <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="Create New" />
    </div>
<% } %>
```

Comment: so now how do i get the Hidden field value in the controller

Comment: @user512967 - It depends on how you code the action method in the Controller. The most basic way would be for your action method to take a FormCollection as a parameter. You could then get the value from there.

Comment: Can u give me an Example for the collection of the Hidden field data In controller...Ne code u can comeup with

Comment: Changing your View Model (assuming its List<Customer>) to Customer type will solve the issue and you can get rid of the foreach loop breaking.